# Filter admin ajax data by url query

Tags: wp-query, ajax, jquery, search

I am new on ajax query,

How can I filter admin-ajax data in the URL query? I am working on a search page where I am getting all the WordPress user data from admin.ajax.php, that is working fine.

Now I need to filter some data by **category** or maybe **name**

http://my-site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=find_coach&category=career_coaching.

Please help to solve this issue

Comment: Hello! It's not possible to answer this question without seeing the code that implements that AJAX endpoint. What's more you're going to need to be more specific about what you're filtering and what you're filtering by. e.g.  filtering posts by taxonomy is not the same as filtering pages by post meta

Comment: http://lifecoachnearme.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=find_coach&category=career_coaching just look at the url. suppose i need to filter user by zip. need to know the url query

Comment: I don't mean the output, I mean the PHP code. If what you're asking is how to filter what you get back in javascript then your question has nothing to do with WordPress and is a pure javascript question that would be offtopic here. If you're asking how to make PHP/`admin-ajax.php` return filtered results, then the PHP code is needed to answer this question

Comment: No really, wordpress hook was set to post user data into wordpress admin ajax. now trying to retrieve the data by filter. that is the same question i posted yesterday and you gave me the answer. look at this thread i posted yesterday. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/360272/filter-wp-user-acf-field-by-ajax

Comment: So this is a duplicate question? If so it should be closed as a duplicate. **Questions need to be self contained**. You can link to other questions for context, but it should contain everything needed inside itself. Right now your question is too broad and vague, which part are you struggling with? Passing parameters to your endpoint from javascript?  Or have you figured that out but don't know how to filter inside the AJAX given a parameter? The Q you posted yesterday was that your endpoint was broken, it had nothing to do with filtering.

Comment: Perhaps what you really need is 2 questions, asked in ignorance of what you've already coded. 1: How do you pass parameters when making a request to `admin-ajax.php`? and 2: Given a parameter, how do I query for posts with XYZ post meta?

Comment: if this case i just need to ask you the correct question on the base of full code. i simple need checkbox filter to be work http://lifecoachnearme.co.uk/?pin_code=Nottinghamshire try click on Career coaching checkbox. you can see the user Duncan William disappear and snehal atif left. but it should be opposite.Duncan William should be appear snehal atif should be gone. it because snehal atif is have not selected in career coaching

Comment: @sleepingpanda Please stop adding "Thanks" to the questions.